# Not able fire the clickDay event inside the calendar at initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I am trying to fire the clickDay event inside the calendarat initialization but its not working but same thing if I do with jQuery classic method to bind method on calendar events, its working!

**Note: I have commented the jQuery classic method to bind**

Plugin used: http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/#Documentation/Events

**Here Is the code**

```
$(function() {
    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
var datas =  [
            {
                id: 0,
                name: 'Google I/O',
                location: 'San Francisco, CA',
                startDate: new Date(currentYear, 4, 28),
                endDate: new Date(currentYear, 4, 28),
                color: '#767676'
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Microsoft Convergence',
                location: 'New Orleans, LA',
                startDate: new Date(currentYear, 2, 16),
                endDate: new Date(currentYear, 2, 16),
                color: '#676767'
            }
        ]
    $('#calendar').calendar({ 
         clickDay: function(e) {
             alert("sdtgfyh");
             var yclick=e.date.getFullYear();
             //console.log($(e.element).hasClass("day-start"));
             console.log(yclick);
         },
        enableContextMenu: true,
        style: "background",
        contextMenuItems:[
            {
                text: 'Mark',
                click: editMark
            },
            {
                text: 'Un Mark',
                click: deleteMark
            }
        ],

        selectRange: function(e) {
            editMark({ startDate: e.startDate, endDate: e.endDate });
        },
        mouseOnDay: function(e) {
            if(e.events.length > 0) {
                var content = '';

                $(e.element).popover({ 
                    trigger: 'manual',
                    container: 'body',
                    html:true,
                    content: content
                });

                //$(e.element).popover('show');
            }
        },
        mouseOutDay: function(e) {
            if(e.events.length > 0) {
                $(e.element).popover('hide');
            }
        },
        dayContextMenu: function(e) {
            $(e.element).popover('hide');
        },
        dataSource:datas,
        enableRangeSelection:(datas[0].color)



    });

    $('#save-event').click(function() {
        saveMark();
    });

    /* $('#calendar').clickDay(function(e){ 
    console.log($(e.element).hasClass("day-start"));
     var dayStartVal = $(e.element).hasClass("day-start");
        if(dayStartVal){
            $('#event-modal').modal("hide");
        }    
     });*/


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code running on Fiddle.

Seems to work for me

A trimmed down version of your code is hosted on [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ys538u25/)

Maybe an issue with your Calendar binding the event even before the calendar is being rendered. As you seem to use a self invoking method. I am not sure if it is triggered well before your html is rendered with your calendar id tag.

One way to check is

```
Add a timeout on top of your function call like 

setTimeout(function(){
  // your calendar init code here
}, 2000); // Some delay to sure html is rendered with the calendar selector element.
```

And check if that is the issue. The code seems fine to me though.